# How change color of text in FAR?

Tags: command-line, colors, far

I use FAR. When run I can change color of text to green(in command line - after Ctrl-O) like in Matrix using system menu properties->Settings...
But when I close and after start again - color return to black&white.
How to make these changes permanent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F9->Options->Colors->CommandLine. There are setting of color for different kind of displayed text.

Answer (score 2):

Console color settings are stored in the shortcut file (`*.lnk`).
Create a shortcut to start Far (for example on your Desktop) and then change colors using the shortcut Properties. Use this shortcut to start Far.

Comment: The colors available to the console are stored in the shortcut, yes (though they can be changed from within a program, too). But changing the color of a specific UI element from the shortcut isn't possible without affecting every other place where that color is used.